How can I hyperlink one cell in an Excel workbook to another cell with the same value in a different sheet?
I'm looking to create a script/macro in a sheet that will loop through all the cells in a specific range in that sheet (Sheet 1, say from B2 to B15) and add hyperlinks to each cell to any other values in the workbook that have the exact same text in that cell.
For example, if Cell B2 in Sheet 1 says "I Like Bananas" and Cell B82 in Sheet 12 also says "I like Bananas" exactly, I'd like the script in Sheet 1 to comb through all worksheets and create a hyperlink on Cell B5 to Cell B82 on Sheet 12. Rinse and repeat for Cells B3-B15 on Sheet 1.
The values are all unique and they will only be located in a range of B2 to B110 on any given worksheet. If there is no exact match, skip that cell. Ideally I'd like to tie this macro onto a button on each sheet that will refresh links on command as things change.
I've tried cobbling solutions together using other stackoverflow and internet answers, but have had no luck in this specific use case. Here is some example code I found from the following thread which I thought might be a good starting point: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-vba-to-search-over-multiple-sheets.333974/page-2#posts
Dim ws As Worksheet, Found As Range
Dim myText As String, FirstAddress As String
Dim AddressStr As String, foundNum As Integer

myText = InputBox("Enter text to find")

If myText = "" Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With ws
'Do not search sheet4!
If ws.Name = "Sheet4" Then GoTo myNext

Set Found = .UsedRange.Find(what:=myText, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
FirstAddress = Found.Address

Do
foundNum = foundNum + 1
AddressStr = AddressStr & .Name & " " & Found.Address & vbCrLf

Set Found = .UsedRange.FindNext(Found)

'Copy found data row to sheet4 Option!
'Found.EntireRow.Copy _
'Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Loop While Not Found Is Nothing And Found.Address <> FirstAddress
End If

myNext:
End With

Next ws

If Len(AddressStr) Then
MsgBox "Found: """ & myText & """ " & foundNum & " times." & vbCr & _
AddressStr, vbOKOnly, myText & " found in these cells"
Else:

MsgBox "Unable to find " & myText & " in this workbook.", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub

Thanks in advance for any help!

Will there only be a single match for any given value in B2:B15? Any cell can only have at most a single hyperlink.

@TimWilliams Yeah there will only be a single match. All values are unique.

The duplicate question link answered mine! Thanks
